# How to attach arm to a static base using SDF

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been playing around with building my own robotic arm. It's very simple and I have all of the joints working. I was hoping work with the arm in a zero gravity environment so movement was easier. The problem I run into however is that the base will always float off or be affected by the arm rotation. I want to fix the base to the ground.

I have tried the following without success:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
  <model name="full_robot_arm">
    <include>
      <uri>model://robot_arm</uri>
      <pose>0.0 0 1.0 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://arm_base</uri>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>

    <joint name="fixed to ground" type="revolute">
      <parent>ground_plane::link</parent>
      <child>robot_arm_base::body</child>
       <axis>
        <limit>
          <lower>0</lower>
          <upper>0</upper>
        </limit>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        </axis>
    </joint>

    <joint name="shoulder_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent>robot_arm_base::body</parent>
      <child>robot_arm::shoulder_rotator</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      </axis>
    </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

It does attach the arm to 'a' ground plane but this will rotation along with the rest of the body.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5065/how-to-attach-arm-to-a-static-base-using-sdf/) by [willy3615](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/574/willy3615/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [willy3615](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/574/willy3615/) on 2013-11-26**:
Please note, I also tried setting the robot_arm_base to static in it's own SDF file but it is no longer static once attached to the shoulder_rotator. Setting the whole model to static no longer allows the joints to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can attach the robot base to the world, which will make it immovable.

```
<joint name="fixed to ground" type="revolute">
  <parent>world</parent>
  <child>robot_arm_base::body</child>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [willy3615](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/574/willy3615/) on 2013-12-04**:
That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

**Comment by [2ros0](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2509/2ros0/) on 2016-11-11**:
Can this joint be outside of any model tags? It doesn't seem like. So there where do I put it? I have one model for the ground plane and one model for robot arm (the base link of which I want to connect rigidly to the ground plane)

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-11**:
You can put it in the robot arm